# Dryer periscope

Tags: dryer

I don't have an exterior wall to install my dryer on, so I am wondering would a dryer periscope through my floor be safe and ok to do? And then duct from the bottom of it out the exterior sheathing.

Comment: My recollection is that the code allows for 35' of dryer duct with deductions for changes of direction (like your periscope), but the manufacturer can spec a longer distance. There it is: https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-15-exhaust-systems#IRC2021P2_Pt05_Ch15_SecM1502. Note that local jurisdictions can and often do override the IRC, but typically they're using the IRC in the US.

Comment: have you considered a heatpump dryer? those only need a drain, which should  already be present for your washer.